# TypeScript incorrectly errors when I map and flat an array?

Tags: typescript, graphql-codegen

I'm using GraphQL Codegen to generate TypeScript types from my GraphQL schema. Here is my query, I've used a fragment so that it has it's only type which is easy to export:

```
query reservationsPage($schoolSettingId: Int!, $day: UnixDate!) {
  roomsForSchoolSettingAll(schoolSettingId: $schoolSettingId) {
    ...reservationsPage
  }
}

fragment reservationsPage on Room {
    id
    name
    children {
      id
      name
      registrationToday(day: $day) {
        id
        checkIn
        checkOut
        importantInformation
        plannedCheckOut
        absent
        pickUpBy {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The data returned looks something like this:

```
const res = [
  {
    id: 1,
    __typename: "Room",
    name: 'Name 1',
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    __typename: "Room",
    name: 'Name 2',
    children: [
      {
        id: 3,
        __typename: "ChildProfile",
        name: 'James',
        registration: [
          {
            id: 4,
            __typename: "Registration",
            checkIn: "06:00:00",
            checkOut: "14:00:00",
            absent: null,
            importantInformation: null,
            pickUpBy: null
            plannedCheckOut: null  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can use this type on a new variable and it works as expected:

```
const childrenCurrent: ReservationsPageFragment['children'] = roomsForSchoolSettingAll.find(
    (room) => room.id === selectedRoomId,
  )?.children;
```

However when I try and use it on anouther variable I get a TypeScript error:

```
const childrenAll: ReservationsPageFragment['children'] = roomsForSchoolSettingAll
  .map((room) => room.children)
  .flat();
```

> TS2322: Type '(({ __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile, "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?: "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; }) | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile, "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?: "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; }>[]'.   Type '({ __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile, "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?: "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; }) | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile, "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?: "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; }>'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile, "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?: "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null | undefined; }>'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do a substitution in the error message text, it becomes more readable:

> TS2322:  
> Type '((X) | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type
> 'Maybe<X>[]'.
> Type '(X) | null | undefined' is not assignable to
> type 'Maybe<X>'.
>       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'Maybe<X>'.

where the X stands for

> { __typename?: "ChildProfile" | undefined; } & Pick<ChildProfile,
> "id" | "name"> & { registrationToday?: ({ __typename?:
> "Registration" | undefined; } & Pick<...> & { ...; }) | null |
> undefined; }

Now we can see that the compiler indicates that the type `Maybe<X>` cannot hold a value `undefined`.
To satisfy the compiler, you have multiple options

- filter out `undefined` values
- use a typecast (as mentioned in Daniele Ricci's answer)
- change the definition of the `Maybe` type to allow `undefined` values

If you choose to modify the `Maybe` type, there is an example how to do that in the GraphQL code generator [documentation](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript):

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but from your question I can't understand if you are looking for an explanation of the cause of the error or just a way to make it works.

In the first case, I'm not a GraphQL master, so you can ignore my answer an looking for an answer from somebody who know GraphQL.

In the second case you could try not specifying the `childrenAll` type:

```
const childrenAll = roomsForSchoolSettingAll
  .map((room) => room.children)
  .flat();
```

or using type cast:

```
const childrenAll: ReservationsPageFragment['children'] = roomsForSchoolSettingAll
  .map((room) => room.children)
  .flat() as unknown as ReservationsPageFragment['children'];
```